# UDP broadcast worked for years, now messages are blocked by WinXP before firewall. Clues?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I developed (in VB6) a small app that send an UDP broadcast message (address 255.255.255.255) and then listen to the answer from the electronic devices we produce (this is to know the IP address of the devices for further messagging).

This was about 6-7 years ago, and all worked well till 1 month ago.
Now the UDP messages does not exit from my PC. With wireshark i can see the UDP messages sent from other PCs, and the answers from the connected devices, but not the messages i send from my PC.
Also, i use Comodo firewall, and even it can't see the message coming out (i deleted the related rules to let Comodo ask permission for my program, but the request pops out only when it sends TCP messages). Even didabling Comodo did not solve the problem.
WinXP firewall is disabled and untouched from years.

So my guess is that a recent Windows update changed something.... but what should i look?
What's blocking UDP calls BEFORE it reaches Comodo Firewall, or how to discover it?
I have no antivirus, and just in case i disinstalled Windows Live Protection ... so really i don't know what to look. I'm an experieced Windows programmer but my API knowledge is mostly about graphics, and i'm not a network expert either (we work with microprocessor, and use TCP/UDP sockets for basic communication).

Thanks

Comment: What does your actual code look like? And have you tried sending to your subnet's actual broadcast IP (such as 192.168.0.255 if your IP is 192.168.0.x with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0), instead of to 255.255.255.255?

Comment: ...mmhh... i should go in the archive PC and reopen that project.
As long as i'm willing to help you helping me :), given that the exact same program works in every other PC in the office (i can see the UDP calls with wireshark) and that it worked until a month ago in mine, why do you think i'd need to change the code, instead of looking for what is blocking it?
I'm just trying to understand and learn, not to saying anything else :)

Comment: You should not be broadcasting to 255.255.255.255 in the first place, but to the subnet's actual broadcast IP instead. In fact, some firewalls/routers will actually block packets to 255.255.255.255 but allow packets to the real subnet broadcast IP to pass through.

Comment: Ok, i did'nt know that. All VB broadcast samples on the web uses 255.255.255.255 (it could be a problem of the socket ocx used by VB working only that way?... too much time, i cant remember)

Anyway, with wireshark logging my net card, if it was the router blocking my messages, i should see the UDP message going out, right?

Comment: This is the code that sends the message, anyway:

If udpSocket.State <> sckClosed Then  
        Debug.Print "Closing UdpSocket"  
        udpSocket.Close  
    End If  
    
    udpSocket.RemoteHost = "255.255.255.255"
    Messaggio = "UDPIDENTIFY" & vbCr
    udpSocket.SendData Messaggio

-- sorry, i'm trying to format it as code but seems that i'm unable to do it --

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, reinstalled VB6 (sigh) and discovered that, as usual, when the problems are inesplicable the cause is often a trivial mistake.

The UDP socked was using a predefined port, and now that port is already in use. The error trapping was hiding the generated error, so i did'nt know it.

Changed the local port to 0 allows the system to pick one random port, which is fine for my purposes.